# C++ initialize blank template variable

Tags: c++, templates

Having a difficult time phrasing this question perfectly, for an assignment I am creating a Template Class. Such as this:

```
template <typename KEY, typename T>
```

Everything works all find, the only one issue is one of my methods is called from another method and has a blank T variable passed in. Now normally if T was always a string, I would just say

```
string value = "";
```

To pass in something that is blank but not null. However.. in this case, I do not know for sure if the variable T is going to be a string, int, char etc.  So I am trying to find some sort of way to pass in a blank value of T. At first I thought I could just pass in NULL for that argument in the method but recieved the error:

```
basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

Because this is an assignment for a project, I am not allowed to change the .h file, so I cant really modify the arguments.

I guess my question just boils down to how could I initialize a blank variable T, which could be a few different things, such as `T t1 = "";`, or if a number T `t1 = 0;`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `T{}`?

Comment: @krzaq is there an option in C++ 98 for that?

Comment: You can try `T()`, but you might hit [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). It should be easy to work around that, though

Comment: Note that "empty" vs "null" is very dependent on what type T really is...

Comment: Thanks everyone, the T() worked for what I needed to accomplish. If one of you wants to post a solution I will make it as right.. Thanks!